# Android 2 progressbars visible in the actionbar when trying to show one

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using actionbar appcompat7.

When I call the following method,

```
protected void setProgressbarVisibility(boolean visible) {
    ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).setSupportProgressBarVisibility(visible);

    // same result with
    // ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(visible);
}
```

I see 2 progressbars not one, the first is circular and the second is linear.

[image]

Is there a way to show only the circular progressbar?

Comment: 1.you can set the progress bar style..
2.Get the support progress bar then set its style to circular 
Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I got the error fast, and liked to share it.

It was because I wrote these two lines in the activity before setContentView:

```
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

Removing the first one will cause only the circular progressbar to be shown.